# What exactly are Link Relation Values?

Tags: rest

From REST in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Architecture:

> For computer-to-computer interactions, we advertise protocol
>   information by embedding links in representations, much as we do with
>   the human Web. To describe a link's purpose, we annotate it.
>   Annotations indicate what the linked resource means to the current
>   resource: “status of your coffee order” “payment” and so on. We call
>   such annotated links **hypermedia controls**, reflecting their enhanced
>   capabilities over raw URIs.
>
> ... **link relation values**, which describe the roles of linked resources ...
>   **Link relation values** help consumers understand why they might want to
>   activate a hypermedia control. They do so by indicating the role of
>   the linked resource in the context of the current representation.

I interpret the above quotes as saying that **Hypermedia control** contains both *a link to a resource* and *an annotation describing the role of linked resource in the context of the current representation*. And we call this annotation ( which describes the role of linked resource )  a **link relation value**.

Is my assumption correct or does the term **link relation value** actually describe something different?

Thank you

Comment: different than what exactly?   I'm not clear what your question is.  See an implementation of this in Apigility here : https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/halprimer

Answer (score 1):

You call it `link relation`, and not `link relation value`. :-) There is a [registry for standard link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), but you can use custom ones as well, or use any other vocab, which defines link metadata. The client utilizes this metadata to choose link.